# Exit PowerShell if Remove-Item fails

Tags: powershell, error-handling

I have such command

```
dir "D:\BA1\xml-data\build-dir" -Directory | Where LastAccessTime -lt  (Get-Date).AddDays(-22)  | Remove-Item -Recurse
```

to remove old folders. And most of the times it works. However some times those folders contain hidden files and this job logs. "You do not have sufficient access rights to perform this operation." <- this is intended.

What I don't know is:

How to fail whole job (set error code to 1 and exit) if that command was not able to remove at least one item.

Comment: Please provide more details about the desired behavior. Do you want an exit code of 0 if at least one subfolder could be deleted? Any item inside a subfolder? Do you want deletion to continue in case of an error (do remove as many items as possible)? Or do you want to exit after the first error?

Comment: The expected behavior was to fail if anything goes wrong so that admin would be notified and can look in to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Your own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51336955/45375) is problematic in that it exits at the *first* error, which:

- may have been preceded by any number of successful removals
- and may also leave any number of removable directories and/or non-removable folders behind.

Instead, it is better to let `Remove-Item` finish processing *all* directories, leaving only the non-removable ones behind, and to determine whether errors occurred *afterwards*:

```sh
# Let the command run to completion and collect errors in $removalErrors.
dir "D:\BA1\xml-data\build-dir" -Directory |
  Where LastAccessTime -lt  (Get-Date).AddDays(-22) |
    Remove-Item -Recurse -ErrorVariable removalErrors

# Exit with -1, if at least 1 error occurred, and with 0 otherwise.
exit (0, -1)[$removalErrors.Count -gt 0]
```

`-ErrorVariable removalErrors` uses the `-ErrorVariable` common parameter to collect all non-terminating errors that `Remove-Item` encountered in variable `$removalErrors`. Note how the variable's name must be passed *without* the `$` to the parameter.

This has the added advantage that you can inspect `$removalErrors` to dermine what specific errors relating to what specific paths occurred.

Answer (score 1):

Of course after posting a question answer just dropped in.

to solve my problem I need to use add -ErrorAction Stop flag and wrap it with try catch

```
try{
    dir "D:\BA1\xml-data\build-dir" -Directory | Where LastAccessTime -lt  (Get-Date).AddDays(-22)  | Remove-Item -Recurse -ErrorAction Stop
}
catch 
{
    exit -1
}
```

Comment: Will this remove some items then, when it finds one that it can't remove, stop? Do you need to fail all-or-nothing?

Comment: Note that this code will not do what you describe in your question. It will exit with a status code of -1 if at least one removal fails, even if one or more removals already succeeded.

Comment: Hi, yes sorry for not describing it properly enough. The core idea is I do not care what gets deleted if at least one thing fails. System admin will have to look at this anyway. So I do not need the job to continue as it will have to be re-run anyway.